# Get users goup name DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to show user group name instead of it's id .
I have this serilizer class for user class  and I used this `User = auth.get_user_model()` for user Model 
but it show NULL instead of theier name .. when i delete get_groups function i will see related groups id why ?

what is correct way to get all users group?

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    groups = SerializerMethodField()
    def get_groups(self, obj):
        return obj.groups.name

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'date_joined',
            'last_login',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'is_active',
            'groups'
        ]
```

Comment: in fields : groups ,so try return obj.groups.name

Comment: it will return null instead of name

Comment: you have any group in db ?

Comment: yes .. 3 group are ready in db in auth_group table

Comment: and any user is assosiated with these groups

Comment: may be obj.groups.name   obj(User) not assosiated with any group

Comment: yes. if i delete get_groups function i will see the groups ID

Comment: if they not assosiated with any group why i can see related groups ID to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def get_groups(self, obj):
        return obj.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'date_joined',
            'last_login',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'is_active',
            'groups'
        ]
```

This would return all grups related to paricular user as `list`
**Example:**

```
In [5]: user =User.objects.get(id=1)

In [6]: user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)
Out[6]: ['grp_name_1', 'grp_name_2']

In [8]: user.groups.all()
Out[8]: [<Group: grp_name_1>, <Group: grp_name_2>]
```

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
groups = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field="name")
```